# Rails - How do I catch and return a warning when the edited values are not the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I catch and return a warning when the edited values are not the same causing rails to not perform an UPDATE?

Comment: What do you mean by values not being the same? What type of values?

Comment: Agree with @Devin, need more information. You could check the params attributes with that of the object itself and not perform the update if they match, but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What I mean is, if someones clicks to edit their date of birth for example, but didn't change anything and just submits the same date of birth, I want to flash a notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle it in your controller. In a basic update definition :

```
def update
  if birth_date_changed? && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
    redirect_to post_url(@post)
  else
    flash[:warning] = 'Birth date did not changed' unless birth_date_changed?
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end

private
def birth_date_changed?
  @user.birth_date != params[:user][:birth_date]
end
```